# Permission denied while creating TPU VM

Tags: tpu

I encountered a similar issue when following the tutorial on using a cloud tpu VM to run [Jax code.](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/run-calculation-jax). The error message is

```
PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on 'locations/us-central2-b' (or it may not exist).
```

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64224796/google-cloud-tpu-gcloud-compute-tpus-create-failing-with-permission-denied), but **it is completely different**. Most importantly, in the original post, people are using the Legacy node while the most recommended methods are using cloud TPU VMs, which according to google is the preferred method.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and is off-topic here. Same with the other question you referenced - that shouldn't be here either. This (and the other) question belongs on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com). Just be sure to read the guidelines there before posting.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot delete it. I will let the mod do the thing.

Comment: It's a GCP and Cloud TPU question, and stackoverflow is a right place.
@DavidMakogon looks like you work at Microsoft and answer Azure questions, there shouldn't be any difference for GCP and Cloud TPU.

Comment: @Gagik - this is an infra question (about setting up/deploying compute resources), so it belongs on ServerFault, as I already mentioned (just a different Stack Exchange site). This has nothing to do with programming, however, hence being off-topic here (this has nothing to do with GCP or Azure)

Comment: Setting up the compute resource is needed so users can do programming on it. And other programmers can face similar issue. Why do you think it should be only programming questions? AFAIK stackoverflow is for programmers and programmers face infra issues all the time.  There are bunch of Azure infra questions here, do you suggest to move those too? any example?

Comment: @Gagik - you're more than welcome to address this on [meta.se] if you disagree with this site's guidelines.

Comment: us-central2 is a weird kind of GCP region, there's only a few references to it online at time of writing, and they're inconsistent. I found one ref in the firebase docs which mentioned us-central2 is a private region that requires explicit access

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that either the region doesn't exists or you don't have a TPU quota in that region.

Please check your TPU quotas and corresponding regions.